# AWS S3 - aws-cli s3api not accepting parameter in a bash variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

I am trying to restore objects from glacier using aws-cli as follow:

```
aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7 --bucket mybucket --key some-file.ext
```

This works nice. However I want to do this in a bunch of files by script but if try something like:

```
$ export I="some-file.ext"
$ aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7 --bucket mybucket --key $I
```

aws-cli returns this error:

> An error occurred (404) when calling the RestoreObject operation: Not Found

No matter what `$I` contains, if I manualy take the value and pass to aws-cli it works:

```
$ echo $I
some-other-file.ext
$ aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7 --bucket mybucket --key some-other-file.ext
```

If I repeat the operation over the same key it returns a confirmation:

```
$ aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7 --bucket mybucket --key some-other-file.ext
```

> An error occurred (RestoreAlreadyInProgress) when calling the RestoreObject operation: Object restore is already in progress

My version of aws-cli is as follows:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.50 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-92-generic botocore/1.4.40
```

How can I pass `-key` parameter using bash variable? Other suggestions? Xargs also fails although with another error:

```
$ {echo list of files one per line} | xargs -L 1 aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=7 --bucket mybucket --key
```

> An error occurred (404) when calling the RestoreObject operation: Not Found
>   xargs: aws: exited with status 255; aborting

or even without `-L 1` xargs print the list of files separated by `,` and:

> xargs: aws: exited with status 255; aborting

Even trying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987592/aws-s3-glacier-programmatically-initiate-restore/20408892#20408892) it fails as `404` like above.

Any idea on how can I pass file paths in a *"script-fashion"* to aws-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some coffee I came back and figured out that while generating the list of files, `grep` command was coloring the output, so some color codes where inserted before and after the match.

I was not seeing these color codes because my terminal configuration. Inspecting file with hexdump (or other editor) it was clear the color codes were messing with paths.

Solution: `grep --color=no` in my list generation script.

My bad!